# Change Mapping for F6 key on Magic Keyboard with Touch ID and Numeric Keypad

Tags: keyboard

I've just replaced the `Magic Keyboard with Numeric Keypad` with the newer `Magic Keyboard with Touch ID and Numeric Keypad` to use with a new MacBook Pro M1. The main difference with this keyboard, apart from the Touch ID key, is that the F6 key now toggles Do Not Disturb On/Off, whereas on the older keyboard it wasn't assigned any function.

I would like to revert the F6 key so that it is not assigned a function - I use this key a lot with FileMaker Pro for use with the Script Debugger. I have this option deselected in the System Preferences > Keyboard as I like to use the function keys for adjusting the volume and brightness etc:

[image]

Is it possible to disable the mapping of a single Function key on the `Magic Keyboard with Touch ID and Numeric Keypad` but leave the other function keys working as normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a way to do this without a third-party app, but you can try using [Karabiner Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org) to remap F6. It has a feature that allows you to remap select function keys. As you can see from the image below, I have unassigned f5 and f6.

[image]